# how to check network change iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm checking the network connection using this example from Apple:

```
- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            self.internetActive = NO;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            self.internetActive = YES;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            self.internetActive = YES;

            break;

        }
    }

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            self.hostActive = NO;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;

        }
    }
}
```

My intention is to first check that there's a connection and then send an email. The problem is that it takes too long to check if the the app can connect to a host let's say www.google.com it takes like almost a minute. Is there a faster way to check for this?

The other question is how to check if the connection was changed from wi-fi to 3G.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to determine the internet connection before emailing? Won't it be better if the email sits in the Outbox until a connection is established? That's generally how email clients work. Outlook or Gmail don't stop you from pressing the send button even if you are not connected. In the many `MFMailComposer` implementations that I have seen, I have never seen any one checking for connection.

Regarding the 2nd question (again, I can't understand the reason behind this), I don't think there will be a callback that will tell you about WIFI changing to 3G. Naturally, you will have to keep polling. Keep calling checkNetworkStatus repeatedly and see which case is satisfied.

Comment: I dont have an outbox since i'm using SKPSMTPMessage to send the email.